# Converting several splines into 3D Mesh

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, spline

I’m sorry if its a repeated question, but I have the following input and want to generate the output like that.

I'm confused about how the splines converted into quad mesh, can I know what terms should I search for?  What is that process is called in computer graphics ?

[image]

[image]

Sample files:

```
Curve1 
https://pastebin.com/KUmk04pY
Curve2
https://pastebin.com/BrpbADE9
Curve3
https://pastebin.com/MX6vWMJg
```

Sample code to read the curves:

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> read_cvs(std::string filename)
{
    vector<vector<string>> content;
    vector<string> row;
    string line, word;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> curve;
    fstream file(filename, ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            row.clear();

            stringstream str(line);

            while (getline(str, word, ','))
                row.push_back(word);
            content.push_back(row);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Could not open the file\n";

    int c = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<float> f;
        for (int j = 0; j < content[i].size(); j++)
        {
            f.push_back(std::stof(content[i][j]));
        }

        curve.push_back(glm::vec3(f[0], f[0 + 1], f[0 + 2]));

    }
    return curve;
}
```

Comment: In which format are the splines given? How were they constructed? Does your QuadMesh require higher order elements? In geometric modelling  the algorithm you are looking for is often called "lofting" or "skinning". It is not a trivial task. You might want to look at [OpenCascade](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/), a FOSS library for geometric modeling. It does have a bit of a steep learning curve...

Comment: But it really depends on your use case if you are looking for a renderer, a mesher or a CAD kernel....

Comment: @joergbrech The input is a bunch of CSV files that has the coordinates of the splines, I would like to just generate a quad mesh, where It has vertices, indices of the quad

Comment: @joergbrech not for rendering, but for saving it as obj file

Comment: The process involves dividing the length of the splines into equal parts and using these points to create quads or triangles. Depending on your input data, you may already have these points in the input file, and you just need to select from that  Posting a sample from the input file would help, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy That would help, and I really appreciate your input. How would I upload several CVS files here or how do you want them ?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I have put sample, 3 Curves in the original post

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Can you show a pseudo code for your algorithm please ?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy I also added read_csv that would read the curves csvs, into vectors of curves

Comment: @AhmedSaleh I might be missing the point, but if you can import the CSV into what looks to me as Rhino 3D, can you not simply export the OBJ from Rhino as well ? I see you've added the c++ tag. McNeel also provide the [opennurbs c++ library](https://github.com/mcneel/opennurbs). (What you're after is 1: parse CSV to get curve points 2. curves to NURBS (as quads) 3. write obj (you can manually triangulate as 2 triangles per quad or leave as quads). For the 2nd part you can search for c++ NURBS surface libraries or if you need to learn how to write it from scratch you can find tutorials. HTH

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks for your insights, I would use your method. I have another question. I have a 2D Voronoi mesh where I want to project it on the 2D Quad mesh above in the picture. How would that be possible ?

Comment: If you already use Rhino3D you should be able to use Grashopper 3D and you can find tutorials on projecting voronoi points to a surface. I'm sure you can find similar algorithms in c++. One naive approach I can think of(and I might be wrong), is sampling equidistant points on your nurbs surface, then projecting/"unwrapping" those points onto a flat plane. you'd re-map the voronoi points from whatever range you have them to that plane. once you have both voronoi and nurbs projected uniform points onto the same plane, you can find the closest uniform point to each voronoi point, then "unproject"

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Can you post an answer with an algorithm in c++ even in pseudo code would be helpful, I know grashopper, but I'm not familiar with either Rhino3D or grashopper..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the resources to do this for a while, hence the comment. Here's [one grasshopper result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iybdwnk_knI). In terms of pseudo code the logic would be this: you need interpolation coordinates along 2 dimensions for your curves to sample points and generate the quads to begin with (e.g. u, v). What if you generate your voronoi diagram using normalised values (0.0 to 1.0, same as the u,v range for NURBS), then use those voronoi normalised coordinates to interpolate values on your NURBS surface ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza as you suggested before, the NURBs surface is an OBJ file now with vertices, indices, how would your algorithm work ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza would that library help ? https://math.lbl.gov/voro++/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250359/discussion-between-ahmed-saleh-and-george-profenza).

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Can I have a chat with you ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza In the same chat above

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza if replacing the 3D Spline mesh with any Triangular mesh that has already UV Mapping, what would be the difference ? I also have the 2D Mesh as triangular mesh

Comment: Triangles are always better than quads.  The "quads" in the graphics above are only a collection of lines.  Draw the mesh first including any interpolated vertices, U,V and normal data needed for drawing , then draw the lines using points from that collection.   That process is tedious and there is no easy 2-lines of code workaround.  Pick a direction (horzontal or vertical...), and work in slices.  Create one interpolated slice (I suggest interpolated beziers splines)  to create a new rib and create your triangles....

Comment: ...  one at a time, making sure they're orientation (clockwise, countter-clockwise) is always the same.  Compute and store using OpenGL glVertexXX(), glTexCoordXX() and glNormalXX(),  (or whatever library you're using) any needed interpolated U,V points for texture mapping, and the normal vector for each triangle summit.  Then draw the lines in a separate pass.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Can you make another chat room please ? I need your help in a topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all the points you need.

- Load the splines.
- Walk the arrays, while summing the distance between consecutive points on each individual curve.
- When you have reached the required length for your quad's edge , elect the closest point as the next summit for your quad.
  (you can also extrapolate to find a point in between points given if the exact distance is needed.

In the graph you uploaded, the 'quads' are actually lines.  The lines on *selected* (by distance between each other) splines are made of many lines between the points given, to match the curve of the spline, and the lines across are drawn using glLine() or equivalent between points selected with the algorithm described above on every spline given.

It is plainly visible in the visual example given that additional points ("splines") were created by non-linear extrapolation, which does not really make the code more complex, but does indeed increase quite a bit the number of points needed to generate the graph.

I suggest you start with only the points given.  The extrapolation can be added when that works.  Whatever code you'll have written by then will be reusable as is with the extra splines added as input.

Selecting all the points necessary for drawing sounds a bit tedious, and it is.  That's par for the course for this kind of operation.

Comment: if replacing the 3D Spline mesh with any Triangular mesh that has already UV Mapping, what would be the difference ? I also have the 2D Mesh as triangular mesh